# How to segue to a tabBarView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a detailsView that contains a link my mapView. The problem im getting is that when the mapView is shown the top navigation bar and the tabbars are missing.

How can I segue to a tabBarView?
I am also setting some variables in the prepare segue method.

[image: Storybord]

```
////////////////////////////
#pragma mark - Segue
////////////////////////////

-(void)userTappedOnLink:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer{
    NSLog(@"The map link was pressed");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowMap" sender:self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowMap"]) {

        MapViewController *mapViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        mapViewController.lat = self.poiDataObject.lat ;
        mapViewController.lon = self.poiDataObject.lon ;

    }
}
```